# Acceptance testing focused on outgoing http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, testing, automated-tests

This may seem like an odd question to ask, because I haven't seen any online discussions or tutorials, so I assume people aren't typically doing this — but are there any good options for automated acceptance testing when the acceptance criteria are specific network requests sent by a web application as a result of specific user interactions? As the most simple example, the user clicks a button, and the javascript code on the page sends an ajax request. The QA team wants to be certain that the request is indeed sent, and that it has specific parameters. Now, one typical solution would be to disregard the network requests entirely and instead to check for the interface changes resulting from such a request, but what if the request does not produce immediate interface changes? Another typical approach is to move such testing to the unit-test or integration-test level — but what if QA would rather see it work in the real browser.

So what would be the options for writing automated acceptance tests that start with some user interaction in the browser and then assert that an expected network request has been sent? What tooling will one need for such kind of testing (as far as I understand, Selenium can’t do this on its own)? Do you know of any available examples of such kind of testing (open-source projects that have implemented it, tutorials describing how to do it, etc.), or could you perhaps offer a detailed example?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is mock out Ajax calls from your front end application in your tests. This is pretty easy to do these days with libraries like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), [Angular's httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), or [jQuery Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax) (a library I maintain).

You can read about the topic a bit more in a [blog post](https://jordankasper.com/testing-front-end-code-without-a-server/) I wrote a while back, but the basic idea is to intercept the Ajax request before it hits the core JavaScript XMLHttpRequest interface (thus sending the network request). In your JS tests you can then inspect the interceptor to see whether or not a network request was made, and what was given to it.

Without knowing your tech stack (JS framework, testing framework, etc) it's hard to say exactly how you would set this up, but take a look at the tools referenced above.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But what you are describing with mocking out ajax calls sounds a bit lower-level than what I had in mind. If you use Angular’s httpBackend then (unless I am very wrong) the requests won't even reach the real backend, and you will have to re-implement all backend’s responses in the mock. No, what I had in mind was having a full-working web application, with the client hooked to the real backend, but with an ability to check the requests sent out by the client.

Comment: For example, what I did was using webdriver.js to control the browser, and also node-http-mitm-proxy to intercept and check the network traffic between the browser and the backend, and report back to the test runner that a request with particular parameters has indeed been sent. It does seem to be working, but looks kind of cumbersome and fragile, so I was wondering if there exist some better tools or strategies for such kind of testing.

Comment: Hmm... I see what you're saying, but why are you testing that a network request was _actually sent_? Do you need to test the network hardware for some reason? If not, why not simply test the parameters being sent into the Ajax request using a mocking library? This removes the coupling to the backend, thus making your tests run much quicker. Yes, it takes more setup, but in the end is more stable.

Comment: It's just that the QA team deals with the final product, and I was thinking of ways to automate their mundane tasks. Tests that would mock out the backend entirely sound like the tests that a frontend developer would do to check the reliability of parts of the app; but at some point the app needs to be tested in its entirety, end to end.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. E2E testing is definitely important. Sorry that I don't have a better solution for you! Sounds like a Node proxy might do the trick, though I don't know of any automated solutions... perhaps that's my next project. ;)